# how to bring an activity (a process) in foreground by clicking on his icon?

Tags: android, android-activity, icons, foreground

I have:

> List procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
>   icon = pk.getApplicationIcon(procInfos.get(i).processName);

I want to launch in foreground the activity relative to the icon when user click on it.
How can I do?

Comment: Perhaps you may want to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int) instead of `getRunningAppProcesses()`. This gives you the top activities for all tasks, so you can relaunch them.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) to display your icons as a button. Then, in your onClick method of your ImageButton onClickListener, call this:

```
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    try
    {
      Intent it = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(application.package.name);

      if (null != it)
        this.startActivity(it);
    }

    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {//oops, no such application
    }
```

Comment: What i must put in "(application.package.name)"  ?

Comment: i have a list of running process and i want to launch a single process and his relative activity.

Comment: You need to put the full name of the application you want to launch, like com.android.radio if you want to launch radio app. (I just made up the package name, but you get the idea.) Your should be able to get this from your list procInfos.